# C++ Constructor explanation needed

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X{
   public:
      X(); // Default constructor
      X(int); // int Constructor
      X(const X&); // Copy constructor
      ~X(); // Destructor
      X operator+(const X& rhs) const; // Addition operator
   public:
      int x; // Single data member
};

X::X(): x(1){ cout<<"X Def Con     "<<endl; };

X::X(int x): x(x){ cout<<"X Int Con    "<<endl; };

X::~X(){ cout<<"-X Destructor     "<<endl; };

X::X(const X &a){
   x=a.x;
   cout<<"X Copy Con   "<<endl;
};

X X::operator+(const X& rhs) const
{
   cout<<"X +     "<<endl;
   X r(x + rhs.x);
   return r;
}

class Y{
   public:
      Y(); // Default Constructor
      Y(int); // int Constructor
      Y(const Y&); // Copy constructor
      ~Y(); // Destructor
      Y operator+(Y rhs) const; // Addition operator
   public:
      int x; // Single data member
};

Y::Y(): x(1){ cout<< "Y Def Con   "<<endl;};

Y::Y(int x): x(x){ x++; cout<< "Y Int Con   "<<endl;};

Y::~Y(){ cout<< "-Y Destructor     "<<endl;};

Y::Y(const Y &b){
   x=b.x;
   cout<<"Y Copy Con      "<<endl;
};

Y Y::operator+(Y rhs) const
{
   cout<< "Y +  "<<endl;
   return Y(x + rhs.x);
}

int main()
{
   Y b(2);
   X a;
   Y c(b);
   b = b + c;
   a = a + a;
   cout << b.x << " " << c.x <<endl;
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
Y Int Con
Y Def Con
Y Copy Con
Y Copy Con
Y +
Y Int Con
-Y Destructor
-Y Destructor
X+
X Int Con
X Copy Con
-X Destructor
-X Destructor
4 2
-Y Destructor
-X Destructor
-Y Destructor
```

Above is the code I have on my hand right now and I have no clue as to how it produces the outputs in the picture that I attached, could someone please explain how the outputs are reached?

Comment: Which part of the output do you not understand?

Comment: Please post the output as text instead of a link to an image.

Comment: @IanPudney I think I have an okay grasp on the constructor definitions, just that in main I couldn't for my life figure out how the output arrived at so many terms when the main has only like 6 calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       Y b(2); // makes a call to the Y classes int constructor
         X a; // call X's default constructor
         Y c(b); // calls Y classes copy constructor
         b = b + c;// call the Y + operator which calls the copy constructor to  make a copy for the rhs variable used in it, the int constructor is used in the +'s return
    // once the + is done both of these temp values are destroyed 
         a = a + a;//since the & is used in the X + operator definition the copy is created after the operation is complete first an int X is created for the return
Both temp values are than destroyed
The cout is displayed
finally the 3 variables are destroyed as the program is completed
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more as to how the values 2 and 4 are computed out of this? Thank you so much

Comment: cout << b.x << " " << c.x <<endl; this line